# How using gl_PointCoord at fragment shader with QtQuick for points primitive

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qtquick3d

For example simple fragment shader for circle points:

```c
void main()
{
   float size = 0.5;
   vec2 center = vec2(0.5);
   vec2 d = gl_PointCoord - center;
   float distSquared = dot(d, d);

   if(distSquared < size * size)
       gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   else
       discard;
}
```

Here `gl_PointCoord` always `vec2(0.0, 0.0)` because it requests `glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE)` but how enable that for QtQuick?

Comment: RasterMode at renderStates?...

Comment: addAttribute for points geometry?...